# return (Type)Instance OR return instance as Type

Tags: c#, casting

What's the difference between (fictious):

```
public Test GetTest()
{
  Object obj = new Test();
  return (Test)obj;
}
```

And

```
public Test GetTest()
{
  Object obj = new Test();
  return obj as Test;
}
```

Is it right that the first approach throws an exception if obj == null? And the second doesn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; both approaches will succeed and return `null` if `obj` is `null`. The difference lies in what happens if `obj` is not an instance of `Test`: the first approach will throw an exception, while the second one will succeed and return `null`.

In other words: Use the first approach if you know that your object is a `Test` or if you don't know what it is, but you want an exception if it is not a `Test`. Use the second approach if you don't know what your object is, but you just want a peaceful `null` if it is not a `Test`. You can also use `as` for type checking if you intend to do something special if the type check succeeds:

```
var t = obj as Test;
if (t != null) {
    ...
}
```

instead of:

```
if (obj is Test) {
    var t = (Test)obj;
    ...
}
```

In that way, you don't need to repeat the type name, although the second form is probably clearer and avoids leaking `t` to the rest of the scope.

Also, see @il_guru's post for some additional caveats related to `as`.

Answer (score 2):

Neither will ever throw an exception on the cast line. In C#, if `new` returns (since the constructor didn't throw an exception) then `obj` is (pretty much, modulo cases where your memory is being corrupted somehow) guaranteed to be good memory of the `new`ed type. That means, among other things, that `obj` will never be assigned `null`.

Given that, I would prefer the C-style cast (i.e. `(Test)obj`) since it's certain to work, and is a bit clearer to read.

In general, the difference between the casts is that C-style will throw an exception if you've gotten the type wrong, while `as` just returns `null`. But again, neither of those will happen in the code you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what was said about NULL in a previous answer (an explicit cast to null does not raise an exception), the **as** cast has some limitation; as stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> Note that the as operator only performs reference conversions and
>   boxing conversions. The as operator cannot perform other conversions,
>   such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by
>   using cast expressions.